# DNS: .ly domain - in google cloud dns

Tags: dns, google-cloud-dns

my company has acquired a .ly domain (managed by the Libyan government), which we'd like to use for our brand. In order to manage this domain there's a very basic management panel allowing me to insert some "DNS Servers". Together with a cryptic message about when it's required to not only use domain names for these servers but also specify their IP Address. Due to bad translation, I can't make any sense of that.

[image]

Ultimately, I would like to manage the DNS configuration via google cloud DNS, where I've created a DNS A record for the domain pointing to our website's IP Address.

This looks like this:

[image]
(sorry for the german, can't make google cloud console translate to english; Type is "Public" and DNS Peering is "Deactivated".)

I've set this up and waited for some hours with nothing happening. Dig offer any information helpful to me either

```
$ dig homeful.ly

; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> homeful.ly
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 42243
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;homeful.ly.            IN  A

;; Query time: 899 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.178.1#53(192.168.178.1)
;; WHEN: Wed May 29 16:47:37 CEST 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 39
```

My question would be: What am I doing wrong? (I have generally only basic understanding of DNS)

Comment: You seem to have fixed the problem yoursef as yesterday the registry did not publish your nameservers in its authoritative nameservers for `LY` but today they are listed so your domain should be fully operational. Or you forgot to do the change at the registrar, or the registry does not update its zone fast enough. Besides, this is not really about programming hence it is offtopic here.

Answer (score 0):

The Cloud DNS configuration seems correct and using `$ curl` and `$ traceroute` commands it's possible to know more information about the issue. Making a traceroute and curl to your domain you have the following messages:

`$ traceroute homeful.ly
homeful.ly: No address associated with hostname`

`$ curl -i homeful.ly
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: homeful.ly`

In a web browser the IP associate in your A register 35.244.164.50 is showing the message 'default backend - 404'. With these data you can have two different type of issue:

1.- You doesn't have the correct configuration in your Domain registrar. This isn't in Cloud DNS it's where you have your domain registered (Google domains, Godaddy, domain.com...). In [Cloud DNS documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/update-name-servers) you have the following sentence:

> 'Now that you have the list of Cloud DNS name servers hosting your
>   managed zone, update the NS records for your domain with your domain
>   registrar. Your domain registrar might be Google Domains or a
>   third-party registrar.'

The domain registrar configuration must has the NS records that you have configured in your Cloud DNS zone. How you can make this? In the same document of above you have the next paragraph:

> 'The process will differ by domain registrar provider and you should
>   consult the documentation for your provider to determine how to make
>   the name server change.'

Without know what domain registrar are you using this is my best tip.

2.- GCP Load balancer configuration. If your domain is working or not, your GCP project configuration is showing an issue. If it's not for testing purpose you can check how is configured your backend service, forwarding rules, healtchecks, firewall rules in your LB.

Check your domain registrar configuration and if you have issue with the GCP project configuration you can open another question.